# How can I access the file extension of an asset?

Tags: assets

Migrated from a Slack #help channel question

---

**Jason Mayo [09:53 16/6/15]**

Is there anyway to output what file type an assets file is? E.g. if its a Jpeg, SVG or Gif etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can access a number of properties on assets. You can get the "file group" (whether it's a document, image, video etc) using:

`{{ asset[0].kind }}`

More specifically, you can access the file extension using:

`{{ asset[0].extension }}`

Full list in the documentation at: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel